# Even horizontal distribution of block elements

Tags: css

I have three divs (or any other block element): `div1` is the parent, `div2` and `div3` are the two children. Both `div2` and `div3` have a fixed width. What is the necessary CSS to display `div2` and `div3` evenly distributed, horizontally, within `div1`? As in the image, I want the value of `x` to be equal for all three distances. I do not want to hard-code the positions of `div2` and `div3`.[image]

You can see a JSFiddle of my attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/pUv85/. However, this seems to place the divs on top of each other.

Note that I want to be able to achieve this without specifying the margins explicitly. In the same way that with just one div, I could set the left and right margins to `auto`, I'm wondering whether there is a similar approach with two divs.

Comment: Have you tried just giving `div2` equal right and left margins, then give `div3` 0 left margin?

Comment: I have tried the following: http://jsfiddle.net/pUv85/. I do not want to have to hard-code the equal left and right margins as #webeno suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really specified a lot in your question, so I have no reason to assume that the following wouldn't work for you.

So just add equal margins to both sides of `div2`, then set the same margin for `div3` but only on the right side, and apply `float:left` to both. Of course you'll have to be sure that `div1` is bigger than these.

You may choose to use percentages to better fit your needs, depending on the rest of your code.

```css
#div2 {
    margin-left: 10px; /* or you could set this to any unit you want */
    margin-right: 10px /* should be the same amount as above */
    float:left;
}

#div3 {
    margin-right: 10px /* again, should be the same amount as above */
    float:left;
}
```

I updated your fiddle that you kindly provided just now: http://jsfiddle.net/7VQRG/1/

**EDITED:** Here is a jQuery way to do the margin calculation automatically - it even has an input to the right of the black box where you can specify a different width for your divs: http://jsfiddle.net/7VQRG/2/

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me (see this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7VQRG/). And in any case, I want to be able to do this without hard-coding these margins. For example, if there was just one div, I could set the right and left margins to `auto`. I'm wondering if there is a similar approach with two divs.

Comment: Thanks, that works well in practice. However, I'm wondering whether I can go about this without specifying these margins explicitly? For example, if I decide to change the widths of `div2` and `div3`, I don't want to have to then go and manually adjust the sizes of these margins...possible?

Comment: not off the top of my head, i wouldn't know, would need some fiddling around... might be possible though... you mean pure css? just because i think javascript or jquery could do the job quite easily...

Comment: Yes I imagine the javascript could do the trick - I was hoping to do it just in CSS though! Maybe it's not possible then, but thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: you're welcome... I'll try to play around with a js solution, depending on if my gf lets me... it's lunch time, haha :)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it in plain javascript, so I created a jQuery script for it, have a look at my updated answer ;)

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers for your efforts :)